# Secured shared login for a white label platform

Tags: spring, security, ssl, white-labelling

Scenario -

Let's say I have a website - www.example.com. I would like to white label it for different customers. So going to example.customer1.com should display www.example.com with some customizations like different logo, name, etc. I have opted to implement this via CNAME and filters and this setup currently works fine.

One requirement is that the user accounts should be shared across all customer sites. So account on example.customer1.com should be valid on www.example.com

Given that the login page should be https and customers are not going to provide me with their SSL certs & private keys, I have opted to perform login via redirect from http://example.customer1.com to https://www.example.com/login?custId=XXX.

Upon successful login on www.example.com I would like to redirect the user back to example.customer1.com - but the sessions on both these are different so I lose the session information and the user isn't logged in when after the redirect.

Question -

To solve this, I am thinking of passing the user id (or some token that can identify the user) from https//example.com/login request to the redirect url http//example.customer1.com/page and then have the white label site load up the user information into its session.

I am afraid that this is not secure since there is a transition from https to http with some identifying information and wondering what better approaches can be taken to solve this securely?

Thanks!

Comment: your usecase seems like authenticating with an IDP/SP where user logins using SAML or Oauth communication protocol and access the resource in any other domain or same domain later. (Like using facebook login for stackoverflow.com and getting user details in stackoverflow), Spring security has good support for spring-security-saml and oauth.

Comment: @AnudeepGade - oauth and spring-security-saml will both require example.customer1.com to be https? We cant force our customers to go https.

Comment: No its optional http or https, basically SAML or OAuth will authenticate users with a centralized user directory or db and sends a SAML or OAuth response which contains user details, the application can even be a standalone swing app or any web app

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

1. Single-Sign-On(SSO) : Use a centralized
   IdentityProvider(IDP)/ServiceProvider(SP) federated authentication
   mechanism where we first establish a trust between client and IDP by
   sharing client certificate in https . Spring security has very good
   support with SAML or OAuth request/response style.

   See [Spring SAML live demo](http://saml-federation.appspot.com/saml/discovery?returnIDParam=idp&entityID=saml-federation.appspot.com) , the app is on http and 
   authenticates with SSOCircle on https and redirects back to http
   with user info.   Yes its recommended to use https for messages integrity to avoid replay attacks.
2. If you are planning to return a token directly from https app, make sure that app generates a unique random id on each login and encrypts and persists the token in some DB and returns it to the http app or sets a browser cookie and then use spring security on http app with a authentication filter and allow access only by checking if request has cookie or the token and decrypt/validate that token with the database where its persisted to avoid anonymous access and configure spring security session management to invalidate concurrent sessions. This is just to make bruteforce attack harder as we have a unique random id, encryption, persistence, browser cookie, blocking concurrent sessions. But if cookie is captured or token is captured ( to capture, attacker needs to access victim's browser for cookie, he can do by phishing attack or any others  ) , still attacker can replay the request as if user because you are not on https. But even attacker replays , as you have spring security session management it will block the attacker session. But if user is loggedout or user session is timedout,now attacker can replay with same cookie/token. To avoid this your http app should handle session invalidation (mark the token in db as invalidated,call user logout in that https app to globally logout the user), so if attacker tries he should fail and redirects to https login.